# Listen for form submit event in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I want to listen for form submitting in a directive. Say I have a directive like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            smth: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, formCtrl) {
            scope.$watch(function(){
                return formCtrl.$submitted;
            },function(currentValue){
                console.log('submitted');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

With the above method I can watch for first submit, but not the rest. I tried to do something like this:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return formCtrl.$submitted;
}, function (currentValue) {
    if (currentValue) {
        console.log('submitted');
        formCtrl.$setPristine(); // Watch this line!
    }
});
```

But then the problem is, if I use the directive in a form more than once, it works only for the first usage.
What I want to know is if there is something like `formCtrl.onsubmit(...)` or any workaround to get the same functionality. Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of watching the `$submitted` property, you can create a directive that has the same name as the `form` directive which is attached with an event handler for form submit that broadcasts an angular event that you can listen in your `myDirective` directive. You don't have to worry about overriding the angular implementation of the `form` directive, it will simply append your behavior not overwrite the built-in implementation.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/C3wiR1hyzWsgueiX2Fkj?p=preview)**

Note: You can also choose not to append functionality to the `form` directive and instead choose another directive name, just make sure to attach that directive name as an attribute in the form tag to trigger the event.

***Javascript***

```
.directive('form', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.on('submit', function() {
         scope.$broadcast('form:submit');
      });
    }
  };

})

.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: '^form',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, form) {
      scope.$on('form:submit', function() {
        form.$setPristine();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

## Update

In light of the question raised in the comment below:

> what's the most efficient way to check if the element that has
>   "my-directive" attribute has "my-form" (if I name "form" directive to
>   "myForm") attribute in it's parent form? So I can either use
>   "myDirective" with or without "myForm" (and behave accordingly of
>   course)

There are several ways to do it:

1. Use the `.data()` method in your `myForm` directive during the compile phase, and access it in the link function in your `myDirective` using the `.inheritedData()` method if the data assigned in the `form` directive exists.

Note that I passed the `form` controller within the broadcast in the `myForm` directive. This ensures that you receive the parent form controller which is the from the `form` element. There are certain use cases wherein you would use the `myDirective` inside a nested form via `ng-form`, so instead of setting `form.$setPristine()` to the `form` element form controller you'd be setting the `ngForm` form controller.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LjbXfSOJ9Tc2guSuJ70t?p=preview)**

```
  .directive('myForm', function() {

    return {
      require: 'form',
      compile: function(tElem, tAttr) {

        tElem.data('augmented', true);

        return function(scope, elem, attr, form) {
          elem.on('submit', function() {
             scope.$broadcast('form:submit', form);
          });
        }
      }
    };

  })

  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

        if(!elem.inheritedData('augmented')) {
          return;
        }

        scope.$on('form:submit', function(event, form) {
          console.log('submit');
          form.$setPristine();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

2. Another way which is probably something that is highly optimized for this specific use case. To create a controller in the `myForm` directive which stores form event handlers to be iterated when a form event is triggered. Instead of using the `$broadcast` angular event which is actually slower than the implementation below because it traverses each scope from the `form` element down to the last scope chain. The `myForm` controller below creates its own mechanism for storing the event handlers. As implemented in #1, using the `.data()` - `inheritedData()` is slow when the `myDirective` is buried deep and nested from a lot of elements, since it traverses the `DOM` upwards until it finds that specific `data`. Using the implementation below, you can check if the required `?^myForm` controller exists in the parent, notice the `?` it represents an optional requirement. Additionally, setting scope to true in the `myForm` directive allows you to have the directive reusable, e.g. have multiple `myForm` directives inside a page..

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1gxSJGvfhswFSazFk3XZ?p=preview)**

```
  .directive('myForm', function() {

    return {
      require: ['form', 'myForm'],
      scope: true,

      controller: function() {

        this.eventHandlers = {
          submit: [],
          change: []
        };

        this.on = function(event, handler) {
          if(this.eventHandlers[event]) {
            this.eventHandlers[event].push(handler);
          }
        };

      },

      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrls) {
        var form = ctrls[0],
            myForm = ctrls[1];


        angular.forEach(myForm.eventHandlers, function(handlers, event) {
          elem.on(event, function(eventObject) {
            angular.forEach(handlers, function(handler) {
              handler(eventObject, form);
            });
          });
        });

      }

    };

  })

  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      require: '?^myForm',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, myForm) {

        if(!myForm) {
          return;
        }

        myForm.on('submit', function(event, form) {
          console.log('submit');
          form.$setPristine();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thank you :). I know it's probably not in the scope of this question but what's the most efficient way to check if the element that has "my-directive" attribute has "my-form" (if I name "form" directive to "myForm") attribute in it's parent form? So I can either use "myDirective" with or without "myForm" (and behave accordingly of course).

Comment: You want to check if the `myForm` directive, exists as a parent directive in your `myDirective` directive?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to be a direct parent. I mean it might be like this as well: form(with myForm)>div>div>input(with myDirective) or anything else...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-submit` with a broadcast or something similar, but maybe first give `$setUntouched()` a try, or perhaps manually set `$submitted` back to `false` after you are done with the current submission.

Comment: I think this needs to be done in the controller, right? I feel like @ryeballar's solution is more generic and DRY...

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: It's most probably not what I'm looking for. I have no problem with sending form or accessing it from controller. The problem is listening this submit from a directive...

Comment: In this case you could try what Mosho said, and put ng-submit in your <form> tag, then broadcast an event to the child $scope (the directive's one)

Answer (score -1):

This post is probably dead but to build on the above, I found the form directive was not broadcasting to the other directives properly so I included everything in one directive.

Here is a simple functions that generates an alert based on form.$error if the form is invalid:-

```
// automated handling of form submit errors
myApp.directive('form', [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^form',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, form) {
            elem.on('submit', function () {
                if(form.$invalid){
                    console.log('form.$error: ', form.$error);

                    Object.keys(form.$error).forEach(error => {
                        form.$error[error].forEach(elem => {
                            console.log('error elem is: ', elem);
                            alert(error + ' for ' + elem.$name + ' is invalid! Current: ' + elem.$modelValue);
                        })
                    })
                }
                form.$setPristine();
            });
        }
    };
}])
```