# AngularJS: Hiding ng-message until hitting the form-submit button

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

This is a typical example of the use of ng-messages in AngularJS (1.x):

```
<form name="demoForm">
  <input name="amount" type="number" ng-model="amount" max="100" required>

  <div ng-messages="demoForm.amount.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">test submit</button>
</form>
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/11en8swy/3/

I now want to change this example so the "This field is required" error only shows when the field is touched (`$touched`) *or* the user hits the submit button.

I cannot use the `ng-submitted` class on the form since the validation error prevents the submitting of the form.

How should I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can set form to `pristine` state on init, in your controller, and show ng-message on $dirty. Or cycle through form fields, setting them to `pristine` That's how I've solved it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-messages="demoForm.amount.$error" ng-show="demoForm.amount.$touched">
    <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
</div>
```

And use a custom directive. See a working demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.directive('hasFocus', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      element.on('focus', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          ctrl.hasFocusFoo = true;
        })
      });

      element.on('blur', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          ctrl.hasFocusFoo = false;
        })
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="demoForm">
    <input name="amount" type="number" ng-model="amount" max="100" required has-focus>

    <div ng-messages="demoForm.amount.$error" ng-show="demoForm.amount.$touched || demoForm.amount.hasFocusFoo">
      <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">test submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

The directive is basically setting another `hasFocusFoo` field on the ngModel controller then we can easily use that directive.

Comment: I didn't get you. How the `$error` state matters here when you just want to show/hide the message on focus/blur

Comment: Does validation set untouched fields to `$touched` state?

Comment: No `$touched` state is set when you lost focus from that field

Comment: This will not work, if the user does not update the field and hit the submit button, the form will not be submitted but the error will not show either.

Comment: But what if he press submit without blurring the required field? The error stays hidden that way.

Comment: @Kindzoku: that is exactly what I mean ;-)

Comment: I do not really understand how/why the on-focus method is called when the submit button is pressed, but anyway, the example seems to work only with one field. I created an example with two fields: http://jsfiddle.net/cgtLznw7/6/  I hope I made a mistake, because it seemed the solution at first!

Comment: Do you want to make it generic?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, at the PC at last.

https://plnkr.co/edit/EX3UmoAOKmTKlameBXRa?p=preview

```
<form name="mc.form">
    <input type="text" name="empty" ng-model="mc.empty" required />
    <label ng-show="mc.form.empty.$dirty && mc.form.empty.$error.required">i'm empty</label>
</form>

MainController.$inject = ['$timeout'];
function MainController($timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    $timeout(function(){
        vm.form.$setPristine();
    });

    vm.submit = function(){
        if(vm.form.$valid){
            alert('yay');
        }else{
            (vm.form.$error.required || []).forEach(function(f){
                f.$dirty = true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I handle this task in my solution. form.$setPristine() - sets the field in a `pristine` state, so field isn't `$dirty` and error hidden. But after submit I manually state required fields in a `$dirty` state, so errors become visible. + if you type something, and delete it after, the error would be visible without submitting a form.

Comment: This seems complex to implement on every form. If I understand correctly you will need to extend the check in the last else-branch for every field and every field error?

Comment: Well, you just cycle only through errors of `required` type, setting em' to `$dirty` state. That's just for a case if you didn't touch the field before submitted it. Actualy in my solution I'm using a directive for this case, so it's very compact solution.

Comment: I see, my mistake about looping over all fields. About the directive: (how) do you inject your code in the submit function of the controller from inside that directive? Do you have a code-sample? Thanks

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have a code-sample right now, but it's similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383507/listen-for-form-submit-event-in-directive